# How to dynamically clone text from element?

Tags: jquery

I am using a system that generates a shopping cart summary in a table with little room to customise. What I would like to do is when the shopping cart is 'empty' display '0'

When it has a quantity in it, display that number.

This is the generated HTML which I have **hidden**:

```
<span vertical="False" quote="False" id="catCartSummary">
   <table cellspacing="0" class="cartSummaryTable">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td class="cartSummaryItem">3 item(s), Total: $115.00 <a href="/OrderRetrievev2.aspx?CatalogueID=0" class="cartSummaryLink">View Cart</a></td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</span>
```

As you can see it currently has "3 item(s)".

This is what is looks like empty:

```
<span vertical="False" quote="False" id="catCartSummary">
   <table cellspacing="0" class="cartSummaryTable">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td class="cartSummaryItem">Shopping cart is empty.</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</span>
```

Now I have some simple HTML setup here:

```
<div class="cartsummary">
  <div class="cartitems">Shopping Cart <a href="#"><span class="cartTotal"></span> Item(s)</a></div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery I'd like to then take the quantity and add it to .cartTotal and if there's nothing in the cart just show 0.

This sort of works but if I add a new item to the cart it only updates the value when the page is refreshed, whereas the auto generated updates dynamically.

```
if (jQuery('#catCartSummary .cartSummaryItem').html() != 'Shopping cart is empty.') {
   var summary = jQuery('#catCartSummary .cartSummaryItem').text().split(" ");
   var total = summary[0];
   jQuery('span.cartTotal').html(total);
}else{
   jQuery('span.cartTotal').html("0");
}
```

Few extra's worth noting:

1. It would be great to be able to have 0 'Items', 1 "item", 2 "items". Rather than always "Item(s)"
2. It would be also great to separately display the total cost in another span. Perhaps .cartAmount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var text = $('#catCartSummary .cartSummaryItem').text();
items = text.match(/(\d+) item/);
var num = 0;
if(items &&items.length > 0){
   num = items[1];
}
$(".cartItems").html('<div class="cartitems">Shopping Cart <a href="#"><span class="cartTotal">'+num+'</span> Item'+(num == 1 ? '' : 's') +'</a></div>');
```

some pointers:

- use .text() to not get any html in the `text` variable
- use a regex to parse out the number of items instead of splitting

Comment: That worked an absolute treat. Thanks for the pointers, your code is much nicer! Any idea's on how to have to value update whenever the auto generated value updates (e.g when a new item is added, without having to refresh the page)?

Comment: you will have to find the event thats triggered to update that value and bind to it, otherwise you can just make a timer that checks every few seconds

Comment: Could it be set to check whenever the add to cart button is clicked (input.productSubmitInput)?

Comment: why dont you try it ;) maybe do that and add a 1 second timeout before re-checking